# VS2017: Debug Assertion Failed shows in Output but don't get the MessageBox with Abort, Retry Ignore?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, mfc, visual-studio-debugging

Have a VS2017 MFC x64 .EXE using MFC DLL and getting an assert when closing the application.  Normally a message box shows up with the option to Abort, Retry, Ignore.  In this case nothing, just:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\mfc140ud.dll
File: d:\agent\_work\2\s\src\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\include\afxcmn.inl
Line: 291
```

In the output window and the program ends.

It started doing it when I added the following (it may not like NULL):

```
CWorkSpaceBar::~CWorkSpaceBar()
{
  // clean up checkbox state imagelist
  CImageList *pimglist=m_wndTree.SetImageList(NULL, TVSIL_STATE);
  if (pimglist) {
    pimglist->DeleteImageList();
  }
}
```

But I'd like the box to come up so I can click Retry to break step through it.  If I set a break point on the line it breaks but F11 doesn't follow it. I find it only works if I static link the MFC library.

Where would I look to find out why the message box doesn't show up and also is there a way to step through the MFC code when not static linked?

Thanks.

Comment: MFC will not display (modal) dialogs after a certain point when shutting down. But you still have all the information you need to diagnose the issue. The debug output shows the location of the faulting assertion, and you can set a breakpoint there. You don't need to single-step from there; inspecting the call stack should be sufficient.

Comment: Which SDK version? There was such a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/51570/assert-no-dialog-automatic-answer-instead-with-rec.html) in an old `ucrtbased`, long fixed since.

Comment: Also important: When are you calling your cleanup code? The assertion indicates, that you `m_wndTree` doesn't reference a valid `HWND` anymore. You're probably just calling the cleanup code too late, but without information there's nothing we can do to help.

Comment: Did you call `SetImageList` previously with non-null pointer? How was that pointer obtained?

Comment: The SDK is 10.0.17763.0.   The code above is in the destructor of the `CWorkSpaceBar` (I'll update it).  It would have came from TVS_CHECKBOX - preventing the known resource leak.

Comment: @IInspectable The message doesn't tell me where to actually find the source and I can't step, F11 just exits the program.  I guess look at the stack trace, maybe it will open some code for me?  I've been dealing with this for a while, I've just been making debug builds static and release using dll.

Comment: FWIW, moving the code to `OnDestroy` fixed the assert.  But I'm more after why no message box and why can't step in to things when building with MFC DLL version?

Comment: C++' object lifetimes often do not map to window lifetimes. Running windowing code from a C++ d'tor will frequently fail the `IsWindow` assertion (as in this question). The moral equivalent of a d'tor for a window is its `WM_NCDESTROY` handler. This is addressing the core issue. If you want to experiment with the debug assertion dialogs you can sprinkle `ASSERT(FALSE)` calls throughout your code.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of debug assertions is controlled through the [_CrtSetReportMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetreportmode) function. By default, failed debug assertions are directed to a dialog (`_CRTDBG_MODE_WNDW`).

It appears that your application (directly or indirectly) changed the setting to `_CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG`. This can be useful in CI setups, to gather as much diagnostic input as possible without requiring user interaction.

If you want a debug dialog to show, make sure to request it using

```cpp
_CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_WNDW );
```

and do not have it changed.